# Как обрезать конец названия файла, но оставив формат. PHP (substr)

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Допустим есть $q = "kartinka.jpg";
Есть ли способы обрезать название вот так kart.jpg?

Comment: Если совсем коротко - да, есть.

Comment: Почитайте про функции str_replace(), preg_match(). Приведите несколько примеров названий картинок, чтобы можно было вам помочь с решением задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "kartinka.jpg";

$newName = str_replace('inka', '', $q);

echo $newName;
```

Каков вопрос - таков ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
substr('kartinka.jpg', 0, 5).substr('kartinka.jpg', -4);
```

Comment: Удобнее всего делать такие операции с помощью регулярных выражений, например preg_replace('!^(\w{4}).*?(\.jpg)$!', '$1$2', $q);

Answer (score 0):

Как то так, вроде универсально

```
$fileName = 'kartinka.jpg';
echo renameFilename($fileName);
function renameFilename($fileName, $charCount = 4) {
    $ext = strrchr($fileName,'.');
    $name = str_replace($ext, '', $fileName);
    if (mb_strlen($name) <= $charCount) {
        $newName = $name;
    } 
    else {
        $newName = mb_substr($fileName, 0, $charCount);
    }
    return $newName.$ext;
}

renameFilename('kartinka.jpg'); // kart.jpg
renameFilename('kartinka.jpeg'); // kart.jpeg
renameFilename('kartinka.jpg', 5); // karti.jpg
renameFilename('kar.jpg', 6); // kar.jpg
renameFilename('kar', 6); // kar
```